# SharePoint Search prevent showing results when loading page

Tags: 2013, web-part, search

I have a site with two webparts (search input field and search results). On each pageload it's searching for an empty string and returns all results, similar to "*".

Querytext: `{SearchBoxQuery}( IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem_GenericList")`

Is there a way to show the results not until the user presses enter or the search button?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you specify If Condition if not null?

Comment: Where can i do this, what's the Syntax for my querytext?

Comment: Using the "?" before the {searchTerms} seems to be breaking an exact match search, for example, if I used double quotes and two search terms as "cloud computing", zero results are displayed. Anyone see this behavior?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try to wrap it in {? }

```
{?{searchTerms} (contentclass:STS_ListItem OR IsDocument:True)}
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. Is the question mark in the documentation at all? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Nope - you Can see it sometimes in a preconfigured webpart. You can read more about it in Mikael's awesome series: http://melcher.it/s/2R

Comment: Thanks Matt! Even 2 years later, you are still helping people!

Comment: Haha - thanks for that one mate. And can call me Matt if you want :)

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar with queries...but ran into a glitch... if you try to use this syntax in the Result Sources queries... it looks like things break... I think because by default, when you build the query there, it slaps on the -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople to the end of the query string, no matter how you type things in... have you seen that before...or know a fix?

Comment: Carp, check the result source "local SharePoint (content)" - that query is defined there. Maybe create a new one without that filter.

Comment: I have tried your solution ,but it will redirect to osssearchresults.aspx page. 
how can I avoid redirect part. 
because on home.aspx page I have search box and search result WebPart.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the Query Transform like, it will not load the results on page load.

```
{?{searchTerms} Path:https://my.sharepoint.com/sitename/Shared%20Documents}
```

Comment: Same for me! any idea how to get this working with the "?"

Answer (score 0):

Still relevant with SP 2019 On-Prem 
The filter by Content Type worked with this wrapper

```
    {? ContentTypeId:0x01001E2AEAE841DFF045A38B3ED40E0C46C7* {searchTerms} 
    (contentclass:STS_ListItem OR IsDocument:True)}
```